Why i'm getting "Key has already been added" in my test
Currently i'm trying to learn to create unit tests.
I have a AddressService, with some methods to get a information from DbContext.
My Testclass lokks like:
public class AddressServiceTest
{
    private Mock<IAppCache> _mockCache;
    private Mock<ILogger<AddressService>> _mockLogger;
    private iSMSContext _context;
    private Mock<AddressService> _addressMock;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        _mockCache = new Mock<IAppCache>();
        _mockLogger = new Mock<ILogger<AddressService>>();

        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<iSMSContext>()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "iSMS")
            .Options;

        _context = new iSMSContext(options);
        _context.Adresses.Add(new Adresse
        {
            Adrid = 1,
            Projid = 1,
            Lfd = 1,
            Sortid = 1,
            Aquelle = 1,
            Istfirma = 1,
            Titel = "TestTitle",
            Anrede = "TestAnrede",
            Vorname = "TestVorname",
            Strhnr = "TestStreet 123",
            Plz = "12345",
            Ort = "TestCity",
            Land = "TestLand",
        });
        _context.SaveChanges();

        _addressMock = new Mock<AddressService>(_mockCache.Object, _context, _mockLogger.Object);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GetStreetAndHouseNumber_Test()
    {
        string street = "TestStreet";
        string houseNumber = "123";
        int lfd = 1;
        int projid = 1;


        var address = _addressMock.Object.GetStreetAndHouseNumber(street, houseNumber, lfd, projid);
        Assert.IsNotNull(address);
        Assert.AreEqual($"{street} {houseNumber}", address);
    }
    
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetPostalCode_Test()
    {
        string postalCode = "12345";
        int lfd = 1;
        int projid = 1;

        var result = _addressMock.Object.GetPostalCode(postalCode, lfd, projid);
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        Assert.AreEqual(result, postalCode);
    }
}

While executing the tests the "GetStreetAndHouseNumber_Test" was succesful, while executing the "GetPostalCode_Test" i'm getting:
Initialization method iSMS_common.Tests.Services.AddressServiceTest.Initialize threw exception. System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: System.Object[].
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryInsert(TKey key, TValue value, InsertionBehavior behavior)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory.Storage.Internal.InMemoryTable`1.Create(IUpdateEntry entry, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 updateLogger)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory.Storage.Internal.InMemoryStore.ExecuteTransaction(IList`1 entries, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 updateLogger)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory.Storage.Internal.InMemoryDatabase.SaveChanges(IList`1 entries)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IList`1 entriesToSave)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.<>c.<SaveChanges>b__107_0(DbContext _, ValueTuple`2 t)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.NonRetryingExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at iSMS_common.Tests.Services.AddressServiceTest.Initialize() in D:\VisualStudio\Work\Infas\isms-common\iSMS-common.Tests\Services\AddressServiceTest.cs:line 50
   at InvokeStub_AddressServiceTest.Initialize(Object, Object, IntPtr*)
   at System.Reflection.MethodInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)

What i'm doing wrong? For my understanding i'm preparing one DbContext with one Entity and use them in one instance of the mocked AddressService.
Maybe i missed anything?
I tried the Testclass above.

But after you run once, the database called "iSMS" already exists, and contains one entry.  Right?

If your test is running against a database, you will want to delete all data inserted by that test after the test finishes, or basically drop and rebuild the database before each test. Just be careful when running these tests against a database shared by other people. The drop-and-rebuild approach might not be viable.

It's not clear to me why the in-memory database is maintaining state between tests, but that's what is happening. I'm marking this as a duplicate. Look at the second answer. It says to add a Guid or DateTime string to the end of the database name so it creates a new database for each test.
